# Android menu item onclick

Tags: java, android, xml

I have added a menu item in an android application.

Here is the code:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{       
    menu.add(1, 1, 0, "Item 1");  
    return true;
}
```

I need to show an alert dialog when user clicks the menu item.

My code for alert dialog

```
final Activity activity = this;
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("Item 1");         
alertDialog.setMessage("This is Item 1");           
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: you have to override `onOptionsItemSelected`

Comment: @Raghunandan I am new in making android applications. Please can you show any code or any tutorial link.

Comment: check my answer it should work now

Comment: there is no need for this `final Activity activity = this` since you can use `ActivityName.this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `onOptionsItemSelected`. Your item id is 1. use switch case and show the diloag.

```
     @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case 1:
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityName.this).create(); // You can use activity context directly.
                alertDialog.setTitle("Item 1");         
                alertDialog.setMessage("This is Item 1");           
                alertDialog.show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

`public abstract MenuItem add (int groupId, int itemId, int order, CharSequence title)`

Added in API level 1
Add a new item to the menu. This item displays the given title for its label.

Parameters

groupId The group identifier that this item should be part of. This can be used to define groups of items for batch state changes. Normally use NONE if an item should not be in a group.

itemId  Unique item ID. Use NONE if you do not need a unique ID.
order   The order for the item. Use NONE if you do not care about the order. See getOrder().

title   The text to display for the item.

Returns

The newly added menu item.

`public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item)`

Added in API level 1

**This hook is called whenever an item in your options menu is selected**. The default implementation simply returns false to have the normal processing happen (calling the item's Runnable or sending a message to its Handler as appropriate). You can use this method for any items for which you would like to do processing without those other facilities.

Derived classes should call through to the base class for it to perform the default menu handling.

Parameters
item    The menu item that was selected.

Returns

boolean Return false to allow normal menu processing to proceed, true to consume it here.